# How to get nested properties to be saved in a new document in a new collection in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, object

I am new to MongoDB and still trying to learn more. I am trying to create a new document in one collection by copying nested properties from another collection. For example:

```
userId: 12345
products: [
    {
        "productId": "123",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "productId": "124",
        "quantity": 2,

    }
]
```

I am trying to get the nested "productid" with their corresponding quantity to be saved to a new document in a new collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get data from one collection and store into an array and dump into another. You can also perform some operations on that array if you want.
Here is working example....

```js
const dataFromOneCollection = [
  {
    userId: 12345,
    products: [
      {
        productId: "123",
        quantity: 1,
      },
      {
        productId: "124",
        quantity: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    userId: 6789,
    products: [
      {
        productId: "456",
        quantity: 1,
      },
      {
        productId: "245",
        quantity: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];
// map data and flat it to one array
const dataToStoreAnotherCollection = dataFromOneCollection.map(i => i.products).flat(1);
console.log(dataToStoreAnotherCollection);
// insert data to another collection
db.collection("products").insertMany(dataToStoreAnotherCollection);
```

Comment: Either way you can use $unwind to deconstruct the array directly from query and insert into another collection.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: Thank you. Tried this. I was able to get the values but i need them to be nested to the new object im creating with the corresponding quantities.